# Firebase is not setting data with browser API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the code I have to set some data:

```
firebase.database().ref(key).set(val);
```

which returns

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

It suggests that I can pass it a then/catch handler, but writing:

```
log = function(x) {console.log(x)
firebase.database().ref(key).set(val).then(log).catch(log)
```

has the exact same effect (nothing is returned/printed either way)

The wierd thing is that this intermittently works, I just can't figure out why.

Comment: I use these APIs frequently, including with promises like yours. What environment are you running the code in? Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem, so that I can give it a try?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It seems like `set` doesn't return anything, even in the promise, but it does actually work. it's `get` that actually passes a value to the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.set` and `.update` are both thenable.

```
function update(node,key,value){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    ref.child(node).update(obj)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Update Ran Successfully');
    });       
}
```